# Updating a different user's session in CakePHP

Tags: session, authentication, cakephp, refresh

Here's my CakePHP scenario.

I have the controller `MembersController` which handles all user information, and also cotnains the `login()` and `logout()` functions. Staff members have the ability to edit users through the `edit` function. However, when a staff member edits a user, the user's own session does not update.

I am looking for some sort of function to go into AppController that compares the users session with their corresponding database entry. If there is a mismatch (ie. the database has been updated), I would like to refresh the user's session.

I have seen many solutions that work when the user is editing their own details, but not when a staff member is editing another users details.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the database you can delete the user's session.
just create a backend for all current sessions.
i use "online_activities" which are connected to the session to track the user_id.

assuming that you have cookie auth enabled (implemented) you can easily force the browser to refresh the user session this way. the user itself doesnt even notice.

Answer (score 6):

Well you could do this but you'd end up hitting the database for the user information on every page request. Your best bet would be to do something like this, probably.

```
function _updateUserSession() {
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $user_id = $this->Auth->user($this->User->primaryKey);
        $user    = $this->User->read(null, $user_id);
        $this->Session->write($this->Auth->sessionKey, $user[$this->User->alias]);
    }
}
```

This checks that the user is logged in and then grabs their ID (*as referenced by the `primaryKey`*) and then requests the the corresponding `User` record from the database. After it gets the record it writes that information to the `Session` at the location that `AuthComponent` expects.